# How to write this conditional statement?

Tags: conditional-content

What is the correct way to write a conditional statement?

```
                    <?php if is_tag( 'Premium' ){
                     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="info"> Subscribe</a>

                    }else {

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="info">Read More</a>
                    }
                    ?>
```

Help Needed.

Comment: are you want help in php formatting of your code?

Comment: yes, how can i add this in template. to show if the post has tag premium then show this or else.

Comment: Personally, I would say the correct way to write any conditional is to add parenthesis around the statement: `if(is_tag())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`is_tag`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tag) checks whether the page being displayed is the tag archive page for the named tag. It does not check whether the ***post*** in a Loop has that tag, which is what you ask: "...to show if the post has tag premium...". For that you need [`has_tag`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_tag)

```
if has_tag( 'premium' ){ ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="info"> Subscribe</a><?php
} else { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="info">Read More</a><?php
}
```

Note that `has_tag` requires the tag *slug* and not the tag *name*, hence the lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php if ( is_tag( 'Premium' ) ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="info">Subscribe</a>
<?php else : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="info">Read More</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```